# Can't see my drawable folders in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable, file-management, xml-drawable

I can't see my drawable's subfolders(drawable_ldpi, drawable_mdpi, ....) in android studio's project directory on left

[image: Android Studio's project directory]

And i can't access images in those folders as well but when i open it in project level i can see those folders but still can't access them in my xml or java.

[image: project level]

And here's the folder that contains them

[image]

Every Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Show us your full directory path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`drawable-*` directories are supposed to be *outside* of `drawable` directory.

All `drawable-*` directories are supposed to be in `res` directory.

Read how it works [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources).

Comment: should we do that with mipmap as well??

Comment: Worked like a charm. Saved my day.

Comment: `should we do that with mipmap as well` Yes, absolutely. There are no nested directories in `res`.